# Does the cgroup C/C++ lib exist?

Tags: c++, c, linux, cgroups

I am currently trying to compile a project (DOMJudge) and the compilation fails on `cgroup_init in -lcgroup`. When I looked to the script I found that this installer was looking for the gcc lib `cgroup` called by the flag `-lcgroup`.

But I don't find any information about such a lib on Linux or other systems.

`gcc -lcgroup test.c` also returned error.

---

I have already tried to replace `-lcgroup` by `-lcgroups`.

---

The software which is supposed to be executed is this one

```
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char cgroup_init ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return cgroup_init ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
```

So with the C and C++ standard, if you want to compile with a system library you use the `-l<libname>` flag.

Comment: A short search engine lookup for `cgroup_init` and a few links followed, led me here http://libcg.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I think you need to be 100% sure about the language you're working in; since they have different libraries and headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply follow [the instructions](https://www.domjudge.org/docs/admin-manual-3.html).**

The DOMJudge authors have already spent a considerable amount of time producing documentation that explains all this.

We can see `libcgroup-dev` included in the package installation command listed in [the "Prerequisites" section](https://www.domjudge.org/docs/admin-manual-3.html#ss3.2).

Comment: You should join chat.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: Why?

Comment: It reduces StackOverflow stress.

Comment: @SombreroChicken: That's not how I remember it.

Comment: We got rid of Jon Skeet, don't worry.

Comment: But in the instruction i see no where talking about how to generate the `configure` file from the github repository

Comment: @GuillaumeMILAN At first glance I can't see where it's stored either. You should ask the developers on their mailing list.

Comment: In fact the build for devel is explain in a link on the home page. Contribute to DOMJudge >  appendix with developer information
Thanks for help

Comment: these links are dead @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 0):

Because the package name is libcgroup-dev does not mean it has to install a libcgroup.a or .so into /lib for referencing as -lcgroup. It could install a libfoo or libbar instead. By that sf.net link above (and this is guess as I don't use the lib), it looks more like the libcgroup package installs libcg for reference as -lcg, which is what the compile command should use, and -dev just includes the headers that assume that main package is installed.

Do a ls libcg* in /lib  and /lib64 to see what actual name might be, I suggest.